# prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\cdots + \frac{a_0}{x^n}=a_n$

Tags: limits

There is an exercise in Chapter 5 (problem 32) of Spivak's *Calculus* that casually claims:

> $\lim_{x \to \infty} a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\cdots + \frac{a_0}{x^n}=a_n$

While I can intuitively see that this is the case, I was hoping I could see how someone would make use of the formal definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ in order to rigorously demonstrate this.

i.e. the "$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ x \gt N \rightarrow \lvert f(x)-L \rvert \lt \epsilon \big ]$" definition.

I am uncertain of how to neatly construct the $N$ for above expression of $a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\cdots + \frac{a_0}{x^n}$.

The only thing I can think to do is use the triangle inequality theorem to first assert that:

$$\begin{align}
\Big\lvert a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\cdots + \frac{a_0}{x^n} - a_n \Big \rvert &= \Big\lvert\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\cdots + \frac{a_0}{x^n} \Big \rvert \\
& \leq \Big \lvert \frac{a_{n-1}}{x}\Big \rvert + \cdots \Big \lvert \frac{a_0}{x^n} \Big \rvert \\
\end{align}$$

At which point, because $n$ is finite (i.e. there are effectively $n$ terms associated with the above equation: $0$ through $n-1$), I could then list out a set of stipulations such as:

1. $\Big \lvert \frac{a_{n-1}}{x}\Big \rvert \lt \frac {\epsilon}{n}$
2. $\Big \lvert \frac{a_{n-2}}{x^2}\Big \rvert \lt \frac {\epsilon}{n}$

...

n. $\Big \lvert \frac{a_{0}}{x^n}\Big \rvert \lt \frac {\epsilon}{n}$

The $N$ I would choose would be the $N$ that allows for all of these stipulations to be simultaneously true. However, this strikes me as a little overly complicated.

Any recommendations would be appreciated!

Comment: I would show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} c / x = 0$ for any constant $c$. Then you just check that $x\rightarrow \infty \Longrightarrow x^n \rightarrow \infty$. Then the limit of the sums is the sum of the limits, and that is equal to what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. However, if you let $A = \max |a_n|,$  and $x\geq \max(1, \frac{(n+1)A}{\epsilon})$ you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\varepsilon >0$ and set $A := \max_{0\leq j \leq n-1}|a_j|$. Pick $M>1$ so that $\frac{|A|}{M}< \varepsilon$. Then, for $x > M$,
$$\Big| \frac{a_{n-1}}{x} + \ldots + \frac{a_0}{x^n}\Big| < \frac{|A|}{M} + \ldots +\frac{|A|}{M^n} < n\varepsilon.$$